# Django Login Page Location

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying to include a simple Login page into my Django project, following these steps:
https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial

At some point I think I am mistaken when I locate the registration folder, which is inside the templates one. My project structure is now as follows:

- project

  - project

    - ...
  - application

    - ...
  - templates

    - registration

      - login.html

But it raises me an error when I try to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login

```
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. application/
2. admin/
The current path, accounts/login, didn't match any of these.
```

It also raises me the same error when I locate the registration folder inside the application/templates one (which is what I've been using for other html files).

In addition, there is a point in the tutorial saying that the URLs provided by auth are:

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

But it seems Django is just looking at 1. application/ and 2. admin/

Any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: What do you have in your `urls.py` file?

Comment: did you include path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), in your urls.py file?

Comment: In my urls.py file I have the urlpatterns list, and at the end I added: urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

Comment: By the way, in the urls.py I do not have included neither planning nor admin...

Comment: Ok guys... my mistake... I was including the auth.urls at the wrong urls.py file... at the application level, not at the project one. It is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was including path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')) in the wrong urls.py file, at the application level. It shall be included at the urls.py file for the project level. :S